# Quinlan Attribute C5.0

Tags: decision-tree

Error in UseMethod("QuinlanAttributes") : 
  no applicable method for 'QuinlanAttributes' applied to an object of class "logical"

I am getting this error whenever I am running a code. I have installed several packages but this error is keep on repitiating.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that C50 does not accept BOOLEAN features.
you can simpliy drop that column or replace BOOLEAN to 0/1.

if "tdata$Windy" is the BOOLEAN feature, replace the value of it.

---

library(C50)

tdata = read.csv('play.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",")

xdata <- data.frame(tdata$Outlook,tdata$Temperature, tdata$Humidity, tdata$Windy)
ydata <- tdata$Play

treeModel <- C5.0(x = xdata, y = ydata )
summary(treeModel)

Answer (score 0):

It's old question but I had same issue today and realized it's was due to read_sav().

I solved applying haven::as_factor to columns that should be factors.

```
data <- read_sav("datafile.sav")
data <- mutate(data,  across(ends_with("_fct"), haven::as_factor ))
```